# What is the difference between Canada B1 and V1 visas?

Tags: visas, canada, business-travel

For a business visit to Canada, my colleague and I completed the temporary resident visa application form in an identical manner and submitted it for processing.

However, my colleague has received a B-1 Visitor Business visa, whereas I have only received a V-1 Visitor visa.

Will I still be able to travel to Canada for a business visit on the current visa?

Answer (score 3):

Canadian immigration explicitly says [there is no difference between a visa for business purposes and a standard visitor visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=435&top=16).

> Does a business visitor need a special visa to enter Canada?
>
> No, business visitors who need a visa or an electronic travel authorization (eTA) must complete the visitor visa or eTA form. The eTA and visitor visa cover all visitors, including those coming to Canada on business.

Canadian immigration websites (as far as anyone has been able to tell) make no reference to anything called a 'business visa' or 'B-1 visa' (it's a little hard to tell because any search for B-1 visa is swamped by results for the US B1 visa). As far as anyone can tell B-1 and V-1 markings on your visa simply indicate whether the applicant originally said they were coming to Canada for business purposes. They make no difference to what the visa allows.

It is definitely permitted to conduct business on a visitor visa.